# Compare two commits of a specific branch on the GitHub website

Tags: github

We can follow https://help.github.com/en/github/committing-changes-to-your-project/comparing-commits-across-time#comparing-commits to compare two commits of the master branch on the GitHub website.

Does anyone know how to compare two commits of a **specific** branch still on the GitHub website.